# Can't get spinner to load on bottom click

Tags: javascript, html, flask, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use bootstrap spinner to load upon button click while flask is processing the request but it's not working.
When I click the button, the request is sent to flask and it never gets to the javascript part for some reason.
To confirm that, I tried the same HTML code below on a separate HTML page and it worked.
So my question is: how to make the javascript code work in conjunction with the request being sent to flask as well.

the HTML and Javascript part goes this way:

```html
<div class="container-fluid mt-3">
  <p class="font-weight-bold">Deactivate User</p>
  <br>
  <form action="{{ url_for('deactivate_user')}}" method='POST'>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
      <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
      </div>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  $('#submit').click(function () {
    this.form.submit();
    this.disabled = true;
    this.html = '<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled> <span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></button>'
  });
</script>
```

Am I doing something wrong? I am pretty new to HTML so excuse my ignorance in advance.

Comment: Have you included `bootstrap.js` or any of its variants in your HTML document?

Comment: I have   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
present in the HTML doc yes

Comment: when you submit the form it will navigate away and browser typically will stop updating.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax

```
  <div class="container-fluid mt-3">
    <p class="font-weight-bold">Deactivate User</p>
    <br />
    <div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
        </div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Username"
          id="username"
          name="username"
          required
        />
      </div>
      <button id="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-primary">
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then

```
  <script>
    $('#submit').click(function (d) {
      let username = $('#username').val();
      $.post(
        "url_for_deactivate_user",
        {
          username: username,
        },
        function (data, status) {
          // if (data) {    // validate response data here
            this.disabled = true;
            this.html = `<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" disabled> <span class="spinner-grow spinner-grow-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span></button>
            `;
          // }
        }
      );
    });
  </script>
```

NOTE: Make sure you replace `url_for_deactivate_user` properly and also that your server gives a response.

Comment: The problem is not in the code itself. The problem is that it's integrated with flask server. so when the button is clicked, the request goes to flask and is handled there so it never goes to the javascript part. I tried the same on a separate HTML doc and it worked. The problem is how to make it work when flask is also there.

Comment: Do you want to disable the button upon the response from flask server? If this is the case, you may want to use ajax

Comment: Through ajax send POST request to your flask server, and then on getting the response, you disable the button and enable the spinner

Comment: See my updated answer with ajax. Let me know if this is helfpul

Comment: It didn't work either. It still goes to flask server's python code and doesn't show the spinner or disable the button

Comment: It's pretty straight solution, if it doesn't work, then there must be something wrong with the flask server. Can you show us the response you get from the server?

Comment: The flask server works perfectly fine with and without it so I am pretty sure the problem is here.